# Whats is the best practice to update child entities in a WebApi?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My main question is whats is the best practice in a WebApi to update child entities after they have been inserted.

Because some child entities could be added and some deleted.

Scenario:
Lets say that I have 2 entities:

```
    Quiz
     - id
     - name

    Questions
     - id
     - quizId
     - question
```

with the following json when I'm going to add a Quiz with some questions:

```
    [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Quiz 1",
        "questions": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "quizId": 0,
          "question": "question 1"
        },
        {
          "id": 0,
          "quizId": 0,
          "question": "question 2"
        },
        {
          "id": 0,
          "quizId": 0,
          "question": "question 3"
        }
       ]
      }
    ]
```

So after that entity will resolve my ids and insert on the database.

After that the user decide to remove the "Question 1" and add a "Question 4"

So in theory the json to update would be this:

```
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Quiz 1",
        "questions": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "quizId": 1,
          "question": "question 2"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "quizId": 1,
          "question": "question 3"
        },
        {
          "id": 0,
          "quizId": 1,
          "question": "question 4"
        }
       ]
      }
    ]
```

The problem is: "Question 1" is still in the database, but the "Question 4" is added to the database. So what to do to remove "Question 1"?

Answer (score 0):

You could foreach the exsiting question and remove it if it does not contain in the passing data:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> PutQuiz(Quiz model)
    {
        var exsitQuiz = _context.Quizzes.Where(q => q.id == model.id)
            .Include(q => q.questions).SingleOrDefault();
        if (exsitQuiz != null)
        {
            foreach (var oldquestion in exsitQuiz.questions.ToList())
            {
                var flag = model.questions.Any(c => c.id == oldquestion.id);
                if (!flag)
                {
                    _context.Questions.Remove(oldquestion);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Rena, thanks for your reply, I thought about that, this would solve the problem but  still doesn't feel like the best way.

Comment: Hi @PauloGentile,If you use EF Core,as far as i know there is no quick way to update the child entity.If you use EF6,you could use GraphDiff. https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff